# Does AWS Sagemaker continue running when I go offline?

Tags: data-mining, aws, sagemaker

I'm pulling data from web services in an AWS Sagemaker Notebook.

1. I'd like to be able to close my computer for an hour, reconnect my computer and see that the data collection has continued to run.
2. Additionally, I'd like my notebook's kernel sessions to remain active so that I can access the data in memory without having to write to file and reload, etc.

Is there a setting to accomplish this, and is it enabled by default?

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't stay at work forever, so I left the Sagemaker notebook running, closed my computer and commuted home.  That evening when I returned to my Sagemaker Notebook, the work had completed running and all the cells and their variables continued to be accessible in memory.

Long story short, if you disconnect from Sagemaker but leave your notebook running, it will continue to process for you.